# Magento 2.2 set/Deploy Production mode stuck at 'Static content deployment'

Tags: magento2, deploy, static-content-deploy, production-mode, minify

I have configured my magento 2.2.3 in server and checked the mode. It was "default". Then I tried to change the mode to production with this command,

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

After executing the above command, some repositories and proxy generation scripts are automatically executed and the "Compilation completed" message had shown.  After that "Starting deployment of static content" message showed and it still showing after 30-40 minutes. Is there anything to do to complete the step?

Note: I have enabled the css minify, js minify, merge and bundling from magento admin.

Server: Digital ocean with 8 GB RAM and 4 core processor.

Answer (score 1):

When you got stuck then cancel that process by ctrl+c.

By doing that you can get your production mode set perfectly but then you will need to fix the deploy error.

Following are the steps to track the error.

Run the following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -vvv
```

By doing that you can see the all processes which is performing at backend and then when it stops then you can check that module. The error must come from that module. So, you can either disable it or fix it.

You can disable it temporarily and then run the deploy command again to check if there any other error or not. If deploy process don't stuck then you will need to fix that disable extension/module.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything in your system.log or exception.log? The issues I've run into the most with static content deployment have been permission or LESS related. Also, is this a custom theme or Luma / Blank?

Comment: Nothing found in system and exception log files. And the theme is default luma. in debug.log file has this content `code` main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} [] `code`

Comment: When I try to "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy", In this section it stucks.  `code adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         1804/2119           =======================>---- 85% %   13 secs `

Comment: What happens when you run the site in developer mode? If there's an issue compiling LESS, running the site in developer mode with frontend LESS compilation enabled may help you flush out the problem. 

Do you see anything in your /var/log/apache2/error.log file?